# ¿Cómo hacer capturas de excepciones condicionales en python? (try, except, pass)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero obtener una parte de un string. El string puede tener este formato:

```
Parte1 - Parte2[Parte3]
```

O también puede tener este otro formato:

```
Parte1[Parte2]
```

Con el primer formato no tenía problemas, estaba usando esta función y todo iba bien. En este caso quería exraer la Parte2.

```
def GetPart(string):
  x = string.split("-")
  y = x[1].split("[")
return y[0]
```

El problema aparece cuando quiero usar esta función para el segundo formato, me gustaría capturar la excepción que se produce de forma condicional para que si no puede manejar el primer formato maneje el segundo.

Algo mas o menos así:

```
def GetPart(string):     
  try
   x = string.split("-")
   y = x[1].split("[")
   result = y[0]
  except IndexError: pass

  try
   x = string.split("[")
   result = y[0]
  except IndexError as e:
    print( "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e)

  return result
```

Me gustaría que si no hay excepciones en el primer try vaya directamente al return y que no haga el segundo try.

Intenté hacerlo con goto así:

```
def GetPart(string):     
  try:
   x = string.split("-")
   y = x[1].split("[")
   result = y[0]
  goto .fin
  except IndexError: pass

  try:
   x = string.split("[")
   result = y[0]
  except IndexError as e:
   print( "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e)

  label .fin
  return result
```

Pero o lo estoy haciendo mal o han eliminado el goto de python porque no funciona.

¿Se puede hacer esto? Y si se puede hacer ¿Cómo se hace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python es un lenguaje altamente estructurado y generalmente en estos lenguajes se considera innecesario y una mala práctica el uso de la instrucción de transferencia incondicionales. En este caso directamente Python no dispone de instrucciones como `goto` o `jump`.

Estos problemas se resuelven de forma simple usando características de la programación estructurada (condicionales, ciclos, etc). En este caso se resuelve simplemente colocando otro `return` en el `try`, por ejemplo:

```
def get_part(string):     
    try:
        x = string.split("-")
        return x[1].split("[")[0]

    except IndexError:
        return string.split("[")[1][:-1]
```

Puedes tener los `return` que quieras en una función y en cualquier punto (dentro de ciclos, dentro de condicionales, etc). En el momento que uno se ejecute la función termina en ese punto. Aunque no suele ser lo más indicado, en Python puedes tener distintos `return` que retornen tipos distintos incluso.

Otra opción es no usar manejo de excepciones y usar condicionales:

```
def GetPart(string): 
    x = string.split("-") 

    if len(x) != 2:        # Si x no tiene dos elementos (cadena sin un "-")
        y = string.split("[")
        if len(y) == 2:
            return y[1][:-1]

    y = x[1].split("[")

    if 1 <= len(y) <= 2:
        return y[0]

    return None           # Para cualquier otra cadena
```

> ```
> >>> get_part("Parte1[Parte2]")
> 'Parte2'
> >>> get_part("Parte1-Parte2[Part3]")
> 'Parte2'
> ```

---

**Edición aclarando pregunta de comentarios:**

Puedes anidar bloques `try-except` sin problemas, no obstante dado que estás dentro de una función y que cualquier `return` termina la ejecución de la misma puedes no anidarlos siempre que cada uno tenga su `return` en el `try`, por ejemplo:

```
def to_float(x):
    try:
        f = float(x)
        return f
    except:
        pass

    # Cadena con coma como separador
    try:
        f = float(x.replace(",", "."))
        return f
    except:
        pass

    # Cadena con fraccíon
    try:
        dividendo, divisor = (int(n) for n in x.split("/"))
        return dividendo / divisor
    except:
        pass

    raise ValueError("could not convert {} to float".format(repr(x)))
```

> ```
> >>> to_float(13)
> 13.0
> >>> to_float("13,5")
> 13.5
> >>> to_float("13.5")
> 13.5
>
> >>> to_float("13-5")
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "test.py", line 16, in to_float
>     raise ValueError("could not convert {} to float".format(repr(x)))
> ValueError: could not convert '13-5' to float
>
> >>> to_float("2/3")    
> 0.6666666666666666
> ```

**ANEXO:**

La captura de excepciones en Python se hace mediante el estamento [`try`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), que básicamente consta de :

- **Cláusula `try`**: engloba el código cuyas posibles excepciones vamos a manejar.
- **Cláusula o cláusulas `except`**: que contienen el código a ejecutar en caso de que el `try` falle. Podemos especificar que un `except` solo capture determinados tipos de excepciones:

  ```
  try:
      ...
  except ValueError:
      ...

  ################################   

  try:
      ...
  except (ValueError, MathError):
  ...  

  ################################    

  try:
      ...
  except ValueError:
      ...
  except MathError:
      ...
  ```

  Para capturar una excepción en el `except` se usa `as`:

  ```
  try:
      ...
  except Exception as e:
      print(e)

  ################################

  try:
      ...
  except (ValueError, MathError) as e:
      print(e)
  ```
- **Cláusula opcional `else`**: es ejecutado cuando el `try` se completa sin excepciones. En este caso el código contenido no está protegido por el `try` evitando capturar excepciones que no queremos manejar.
- **Cláusula opcional  `finally`**: siempre se ejecuta antes de terminal bloque, se haya producido o no una excepción. Cuando se ha producido una excepción en la cláusula `try` y no ha sido manejada por una cláusula `except`se vuelve a lanzar después de que se haya ejecutado la cláusula `finally`. **Instrucciones de salida como  `break`, `continue` o `return` no evitan que `finally` se ejecute antes de ejecutarlas**.

La instrucción `pass` simplemente "no hace nada", se usa cuando declaramos un bloque que no puede estar vacío en cuanto a sintaxis (ocasiona un `IdentationError`) cómo`if`, `elif`, `else`, `except`, `def` o`class`,  pero que no queremos que haga nada, al menos por el momento.

Comment: Gracias!! Funciona perfecto!! Y si por ejemplo tuviera que manejar mas de dos casos ¿Cómo lo haría?

Comment: ¿@IvánRodríguez te refieres a tener varios bloques `try-except`? Como digo puedes tener un `return` en cada uno sin problemas. Si la función no debe retornar en cada bloque `try-except` puedes usar condicionales (`if-else-elif`) para retornar cosas diferentes en base a determinadas condiciones. Si no te aclaras no dudes en editar la pregunta añadiendo un ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias otra vez por extender la respuesta @FJSevilla

Comment: SI, exacto!! a eso me referia... a tener varios bloques {try-except}... es decir, con un bloque {try-except} solo puedo manejar dos casos... pero ya lo voy pillando. porque podría poner otro bloque  {try-except} dentro de último "except" ¿Verdad? y así manejar un tercer caso y/o un cuarto si fuera necesario.

Comment: Creo que con todo eso tengo mas que suficiente para resolver todos mis problemas. Gracias de nuevo @FJSevilla. Un Saludo!!

Comment: @IvánRodríguez he editado la respuesta otra vez, no había visto tu edición corrigiendo la pregunta en la que has modificado los formatos posibles, aunque la esencia sigue siendo la misma. En cuanto a la última duda que planteabas he añadido un pequeño ejemplo, puedes anidar `try-except` sin problemas pero puedes también no hacerlo siempre que cada uno tenga su `return`. Un saludo.

Comment: Eso último es exatamente a lo que me refería, ni mas ni menos, es perfecto!! No sé cuantas veces te habré dado las gracias pero con todo lo que te lo has currado creo que son pocas... Un Saludo!! :-)